# Как сделать чтобы выбранные из списка значения накапливались в поле формы?

Tags: vba, visual-basic, ms-access

**Используется**
Access 2016

Сценарий:
- вводим первые символы значения из списка;
- список "подкидывает" в строку ввода наиболее подходящее значение из списка;
- наживаем "Ввод";
- Выбранное значение попадает в поле формы "Поле1" через **запятую**;
и т.д. для остальных значений.

Файл - [ссылка](http://transfiles.ru/pjuv7)

**Вопрос.**
Как сделать чтобы выбранные в списке значения накапливались в поле формы через запятую?
Значение предполагается использовать: текстовые, числовые, текстовые+числовые.

**Рисунок**
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `sub znak_keypress:Поле1.Text=Поле1.Text&','&znak.Text` - само собой, с добавлением проверок на дублирование, существование и протчая.

Comment: @Akina Сделал так. Правильно? Или может, что-то не учёл? Код https://codeshare.io/5wgXR5